# PHP: Require Dynamic file paths in init.php

Tags: php, ajax, directory

So I just decided to process forms on a project of mine using Ajax.

As usual, I send over the received Input data via Ajax to process.php which is then supposed to validate it using the Input.php class in the classes folder.

However, as file paths in my init.php are hardcoded, the script is searching for the Input class in **ajax/classes/Input.php** instead of **classes/Input.php**

Can I tweak my init file somehow or do I have to come up with a different Directory structure?

Here is the current **structure**:

```
ajax/
    process.php
classes/
    Input.php
core/
    init.php
js/
    ajax.js  
form.php
```

Begin of **process.php**

```
<?php
require_once '../core/init.php';
[...]
```

Relevant part of **init.php**

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    require_once 'classes/'.$class.'.php';
});
```

I tried to do something like require_once 'init.php?subdir=true' but as including is not a http request it obviously didn't work.

I would be very happy if someone here would give me a hand!

If anything is unclear, please ask!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use for example something like this:

```
 spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
require_once __DIR__.'/../classes/'.$class.'.php';
```

});

So your init.php will require other scripts by path relative to his own dir. And I would say that is very unlikely to change init.php file location, but even if you do you will have to make minor changes only in init.php

Comment: Damn, why can't I think about such easy things myself? I've even googled and read about `__FILE__` but couldn't figure out how I could use it to in my initialization file.

Comment: Thanks alot @krasipenkov !!